# How to search for a specific word within a text?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a file, of type txt, with the following text:

The dataset is available at: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.php
The file name is Cancer_Data.xml
This is one of three domains provided by the Oncology Institute that has repeatedly appeared in the machine learning literature.

I need to search within this text the word that accompanies the "xml". I tried to do the following implementation:

```
      import pandas as pd

      with open(local_arquivo, "r") as file_read:   
          for line in file_read:        
              var_split = line.split()
              for i in range(0, len(var_split)):
                  if(var_split[i].str.contains('xml')):
                      archive_name = var_split.iloc[i]
```

The idea was to separate the text using the split function and then look for the part that contains the 'xml'. However, when I run it, the following error appears:

```
        AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

I would like the output to be:

archive_name = Cancer_Data.xml

Comment: Remove `.str`, your line is already a `str`, you are reading a file of text. The error messages in python are normally pretty explicit if you can trace the point of failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
if('xml' in var_split[i]):
```

source: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks!
The correct implementation is: if('XML' in var_split[i]):            
                archive_name = var_split[i]